# A right triangle with natural numbered sides and area $=abcd$

Tags: geometry, number-theory, triangles

Let $a,b,c$ and $d$ be natural numbers such that $a+b=c$ and $a+d=2c$ .

Prove that there is a right triangle with natural-numbered sides and area $=abcd$.

My try :

$x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}$ and $S=\frac{x+y}{2}$

But I don't have no ideas to continue.

Answer (score 2):

We require a right angle triangle whose area is $abcd=ab(a+b)(a+2b)$ (using the constraints.)

The lengths of a right angle triangle can be paramerised by
\begin{eqnarray*}
x&=& \alpha^2- \beta^2 \\
y&=& 2 \alpha \beta \\
z&=& \alpha^2+ \beta^2. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
This triangle will have area $ \alpha \beta (\alpha- \beta)(\alpha+ \beta)$. Now choose $ \alpha= \beta+\gamma$ and the area becomes $  \beta  \gamma( \beta +\gamma)(2 \beta+\gamma)$. So the area of every right angle triangle has the aforementioned form!

Comment: A nice answer but the argument that  the area of every right angled triangle has the aforementioned form is not correct. The issue is that your parametrisation is only for a primitive right angled triangle.